# jQuery/Javascript - scroll with 'j' and 'k' keys?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div on my page that will scroll up/down on `overflow-y`. Currently, it is possible to scroll up and down with the up/down arrow keys as well as the mouse wheel. How would I add the ability to scroll down with the 'j' key and up with the 'k' key? The part I don't know how to do (and can't seem to find any documentation for) is how to tell a div to scroll once I have captured the 'j' and 'k' keypress events. Here's what I have so far:

```
$('#my-div').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keycode === 74) {
        // how to scroll down?
        console.log('j!');
    }
    else if (e.keycode === 75) {
        // how to scroll up?
        console.log('k!');
    }
}
```

Comment: You bind a key event handler to the element or the document, depending on how exactly you want to do this. Where exactly are you stuck? How to bind event handlers? How to test which key was pressed? How to scroll an element?

Comment: I know how to capture keydown events and determine which key it was, but once that happens, how do I instruct the div to scroll up/down accordingly?

Comment: Please [edit] your question accordingly and include a small example of what you have so far.

Comment: Done! (extra chars for req)

Comment: @CodyMa Add offset with `$(this)[0].scrollTop += 20` or `$(this)[0].scrollTop -= 20`, depending on which key was pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a fiddle demonstrating: http://jsfiddle.net/BmY6w/

For `#my-div` to respond to `keydown` events, the element needs focus. You could work around this by using `$(document)` and bind keydown that way - however, I've added a tabindex (to the fiddle) that allows you to click it and then use your keyboard's J/K keys.

```
$('#my-div').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keycode === 74) {
        $(this)[0].scrollTop += 20;
    }
    else if (e.keycode === 75) {
        // how to scroll up?
        $(this)[0].scrollTop -= 20;
    }
}
```

As you can see, changing the scrollTop offset is the easiest.

You could get fancy with `animate` like this: `$(this).animate({scrollTop: cur - 30}, 200);`

Updated fiddle w/ animation: http://jsfiddle.net/BmY6w/1/

**Edit 1:**

With the animated fiddle, you may have noticed some weirdness when holding down the j or k button. This was due to the events queueing up. Here's an updated fiddle to include basic throttling:

http://jsfiddle.net/BmY6w/2/

**Edit 2:**

Constant speed isn't always fun. Let's add some acceleration! Here's a fiddle example with basic acceleration (cleaned up the script as well):

http://jsfiddle.net/BmY6w/3/

The values `speed` and `accelerator` will allow you to fine tune the acceleration and motion as you hold down the j/k buttons.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! This seems to do some funky things when I hold down the 'j' or 'k' key (div freezes and jerks around a bit), any idea how to fix that?

Comment: @CodyMa When holding down 'j' or 'k', it'll overload the handler causing the funkiness (primarily with the animated one - the non-animated one should just scroll). If you throttle the handler, it'll work as intended. I've added basic throttling here: http://jsfiddle.net/BmY6w/2/

Comment: Ah great thanks so much! I've marked your answer as the accepted one. One follow up question - I understand what you did the the Date, but is there a way to make the 'j' and 'k' perform smoother scrolling like the arrow keys do? As you hold down the down arrow, the page will accelerate it's scrolling, whereas this current implementation goes at the same rate down the page

Comment: @CodyMa - Thanks Cody! I've added another edit to include acceleration!